# Import user control to live website

Tags: user-controls, webforms

I have a website, which imports user controls (.ascx) into a directory of a live website.

Obviously, once the user control is imported into the directory, it is not actually 'part' of the website, it's just a .ascx file sitting in a directory on the website.

When I try to add the user control to a panel, I get a "Could not load type 'CMS.Modules.HelloWorld'." error.

```
    Control content = LoadControl(@"~/Modules/" + ddlExtraModules.SelectedValue.ToString() + "/HelloWorld.ascx");
    pnlSections.Controls.Add(content);
```

Is it actually possible to add user controls to a website 'on the fly'?

Comment: Does the assembly used by the user control exist in the bin folder?

Comment: No, but I also have some User Controls that were compiled with the website and there is no reference to these in the bin file, but they work.

Comment: Looks like you can dynamically add ascx files as web applications jit compile (just in time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can dynamically add ascx files to web applications as they are compiled at run time. Use them only on webforms and do not request them directly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol.aspx

> In addition, the designer creates the @ Register directive, which is
>   required for the page to recognize the user control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d0t5fak%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Adding the @Register directive using the designer is not an option. The idea behind all this is each website "purchases" user controls. These are then uploaded to a folder which has the same name as a unique ID in a usercontrols table i.e: ~/Modules/85/HelloWorld.ascx. From a dropdown which is bound to this table, the user control is added - LoadControl(~/Modules/85/HelloWOrld.ascx).

Comment: In that case you can not (not with loadcontrol):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0az2h86%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

"LoadControl method. First, however, you must associate a strong type with the user control by using the className attribute on the @ Control directive" Maybe if you not cast it to a specific type it'll work but you can't invoke specific functions of that usercontrol.